# Push and Pop on AMD64

Tags: assembly, stack, x86-64

What is the equivilent of `pushl %ecx` and `popl %ecx` on a AMD64 sytem, My results are `Error: invalid instruction suffix for 'push'` I have had a look and some one suggested changing `ecx` to `rcx` but that just resulted in `Incorrect register '%rcx' used with 'l' suffix`

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On AMD64, `push` and `pop` operations are implicitly 64-bits and have no 32-bit counterparts. Try:

```
pushq %rcx
popq %rcx
```

See [here](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/assembly.html) for details.