# How can I compile a 32-bit .o file with gcc in my 64-bit machine?

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, nasm

Trying to learn NASM Assembly. I have a 64-bit machine, with Ubuntu. Recently I decided to test the `push` and `pop` instructions. I do this:

```
nasm -felf64 Test.asm
```

Apparently they are not supported in 64-bit mode. Alright, no problem, I'll just do it for 32 then:

```
nasm -felf Test.asm
```

And now, as always,

```
gcc Test.o
```

But it now tells me

```
i386 architecture of input file 'Test.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
```

I don't quite grasp the error here. How can I test `push` and `pop` in my 64-bit machine, if apparently I can't compile 32-bit programs?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050186/push-and-pop-on-amd64 , also the asm language is really really really platform-dependant, you should never expect a given keyword/register/function, to work on any platform, if it happens it's a free meal, but normally there is plenty of differences, even under the same OS with different "bitness".

Comment: @user2485710: I see. That's not very nice for students trying to do things at home :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about "-m32"?
And I think you need to care dependent library(e.g libc), see: [Use 32bit shared library from 64bit application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039401/use-32bit-shared-library-from-64bit-application/)

Answer (score 2):

First, you can use `push` and `pop` in 64-bit code, just not with 32-bit registers. If you `push` and `pop` 64-bit registers, it'll work fine. In most cases, you can use 32-bit registers in 64-bit code, just not `push` and `pop`. There may be other exceptions, but I'm not aware of 'em.

64-bit code uses different system call numbers, puts the parameters in different registers, and uses `syscall` instead of `int 0x80`. However, the old `int 0x80` interface with the old system call numbers and parameters in the old registers still works. This gives you kind of "mixed" code and may not be a Good Idea, but it works. How long it will continue to work in future kernels is anybody's guess. You may be better off to learn "proper" 64-bit code.

But there are (still!) a lot more 32-bit examples out there. You can tell Nasm `-f elf32` (just `-f elf` is an alias, but I'd use the "full name" just for clarity). If you're using gcc, tell it `-m32`. If you're using ld directly, tell it `-m elf_i386`. You do have choices, but they have to be compatible with each other.

Answer (score 0):

how about the "-march=i386" ? see:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html

Comment: that's likely to not be the answer, `march` it's about optimization, not about what platform you would like to pick at compile time.