# linking assembler generated obj file

Tags: assembly, nasm, ld

I am trying to learn (or at least understand) assembly on windows. I found this Hello World example somewhere and I want to make an .exe out of it just to be sure I have everything set up correctly.
For people that will post other Hello World examples I want to make clear I am looking for one with direct windows api calls.

```
        global  _start
        extern  _ExitProcess@4
        extern  _GetStdHandle@4
        extern  _WriteConsoleA@20

        section .data
msg:    db      'Hello, World', 10
handle: db      0
written:
        db      0

        section .text
_start:
        ; handle = GetStdHandle(-11)
        push    dword -11
        call    _GetStdHandle@4
        mov     [handle], eax

        ; WriteConsole(handle, &msg[0], 13, &written, 0)
        push    dword 0
        push    written
        push    dword 13
        push    msg
        push    dword [handle]
        call    _WriteConsoleA@20

        ; ExitProcess(0)
        push    dword 0
        call    _ExitProcess@4
```

I assemble it successfully like so

```
nasm -fwin32 hello.asm
```

Then when I try to link it with ld like so

```
ld hello.obj -lkernel32
```

It produces an executable but when I try to run it I get this

```
Program 'a.exe' failed to run: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.At line:1 char:1
+ .\a.exe
+ ~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\a.exe
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

I even downloaded ALINK but whenever I try to link it like so

```
ALINK hello.obj C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll
```

I get this output

```
ALINK v1.6 (C) Copyright 1998-9 Anthony A.J. Williams.
All Rights Reserved

Loading file .\programs\hello.obj
Loading file C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll
Unsupported CPU type for module
```

what flags do I have to pass to the linkers, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write hello world in assembler under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023593/how-to-write-hello-world-in-assembler-under-windows)

Comment: @Barbo24 You can find more HelloWorld examples with direct WinAPI invokations at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63388863/fasm-write-hello-world-to-console-with-no-includes-or-dependencies-at-all/63402718#63402718

Answer (score 3):

You are linking it wrong. Unlike FASM or €ASM, the linker ALINK is not capable to fetch import information from Dynamic Linked Library *on the fly*, it needs an import library. One such library `WIN32.lib` is shipped with ALINK or you can generate it yourself. e.g. by [dll2lib](https://euroassembler.eu/prowin32/dll2lib.htm) or similar tool.

Then you should fix errors in your source:

1. Memory variables `handle` and `written` should be DWORD, not BYTE.
2. Remove decoration from names of imported functions. Use `ExitProcess` instead of `_ExitProcess@4` etc., exactly as they are defined at [Microsoft API doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getstdhandle)

Make your executable with

```
nasm -fwin32 barbo24.asm
alink barbo24.obj WIN32.lib -oPE -entry _start -subsys con
barbo24.exe
```

If it doesn't write `Hello, world`, check and debug it with

```
peview.exe barbo24.exe
ollydbg barbo24.exe
```