# I get a few errors, including Hello.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _StdOut@4, when I try to link .obj file (ASSEMBLY)?

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

I am a beginner in assembly. I install masm32..... Getting the .obj file worked perfectly, but when I tried to link it(turn it into .exe file) I got 4 errors. This is my code: `

```
.386

.model flat,stdcall

option casemap :none
include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include \masm32\include\masm32.inc

includelib \masm32\include\kernel32.lib
includelib \masm32\include\masm32.lib
.data
HelloWorld db "Hello World!",0
.code
start:
invoke StdOut, addr HelloWorld
invoke ExitProcess,0
end start`
```

, and here are the errors that I got:
`

```
Hello.obj : warning LNK4033: converting object format from OMF to COFF

Hello.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _StdOut@4

Hello.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ExitProcess@4

LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mainCRTStartup

Hello.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

I really don't know what could be the problem, can someone help?

Comment: People at [MASM forum](http://masm32.com/board/index.php?topic=706.msg5915) might help you. Or try a different toolset, see [linking assembler generated obj file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66627365/linking-assembler-generated-obj-file/66642248#66642248)

Comment: Thank you, I will ask there.....